# How to redirect one or more GET requests to a different directory or file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So, I have a site with an index.php and GET requests are sent to it (or root /).

E.g. `http://example.com/index.php?category=Birthday`

or `http://example.com/?category=Birthday`.

I'd like to be able to 301 redirect only these specific requests to a new directory `http://example.com/templates/?category=Birthday`

I've tried matching part of the GET request in the .htaccess file `?category=` but it results in an infinite loop as soon as it hits the new directory. That and I have huge difficulties understanding RegEx.

All the other help and tutorials do the task of matching **all** requests to a new directory but I would like the redirect to only be effective upon use of `?category=`

My .htaccess file is otherwise blank and has no other special rewrites. I'll be able to post code on request if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)category= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /templates/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

`QUERY_STRING` will be automatically carried over to target URI.

Comment: That is absolutely perfect! It even carries the whole query over to the new location if any other GET parameters are used, which is really nice. Thank you very much for your help @anubhava . I had no idea about `QUERY_STRING` but I'm glad I do now.